# Use of unnasigned variable - for loop

Tags: c#

I have a question regarding assigning value to a variable inside a `for` loop. I understand that the compiler gives this error message when there is any possibility that a variable may be read when it is not yet assigned, as stated by Microsoft.

> Note that this error is generated when the compiler encounters a construct that might result in the use of an unassigned variable, even if your particular code does not.

My code looks like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i;

    for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++)
    {
        i = j;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I presume that even though in this particular scenario `i` will get assigned, the compiler doesn't check the actual condition inside the `for` statement, meaning that it would treat

```
for (int j = 0; j <= -1; j++)
```

just the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current case seems trivial, but what if your loop looks like this:

```
int i;

for (int j = 0; j <= GetUpperLimit(); j++)
{
    i = j;
}
```

`GetUpperLimit` could return 5 like it could return -3 and `i` will never get assigned. It could be entirely dependent on the state of your application during runtime and the compiler can't know that beforehand, obviously. A simple `int i = 0` will solve the issue.

If the condition is a false `const` or a literal, your for loop will be optimized away. Demo using LINQPad:

```
int i;

for (int j = 0; j <= -1; j++)
{
    i = j;
}
```

Resulting IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.1     // j
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_000D
IL_0005:  nop         
IL_0006:  ldloc.1     // j
IL_0007:  stloc.0     // i
IL_0008:  nop         
IL_0009:  ldloc.1     // j
IL_000A:  ldc.i4.1    
IL_000B:  add         
IL_000C:  stloc.1     // j
IL_000D:  ldloc.1     // j
IL_000E:  ldc.i4.m1   
IL_000F:  cgt         
IL_0011:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0012:  ceq         
IL_0014:  stloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_0015:  ldloc.2     // CS$4$0000
IL_0016:  brtrue.s    IL_0005
```

Now with a false literal instead of an expression:

```
int i;

for (int j = 0; false; j++)
{
    i = j;
}
```

Resulting IL:

```
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0002:  stloc.1     // j
IL_0003:  br.s        IL_0005
IL_0005:  ldc.i4.0    
IL_0006:  stloc.2     // CS$4$0000
```

Similarly, `if(false) { ... }` is optimized, but not `bool b = false; if(b) { ... }`. This is all a result of static analysis.

Comment: You're right that in your example the compiler won't know this beforehand - but in mine it will. Hence the slight confusion.

Answer (score 13):

Since you are assigning value to variable `i` inside your for loop, compiler is not smart enough to see whether it will be assigned any value, hence the error.

A simple solution would be to assign some default value to your variable.

```
int i = 0;
```

Although from the loop variable values it appears that the control will enter the `for` loop, but the compiler can't determine that.

The reason for the error is because of the language specification,

[5.3 Definite assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

> At a given location in the executable code of a function member, a
>   variable is said to be definitely assigned if the compiler can prove,
>   **by static flow analysis**, that the variable has been automatically initialized or has been the target of at least one assignment.

Evaluation a condition is not static flow, it would be determined at runtime. Because of that the compiler can't determine whether `i` would be assigned any value.

Comment: Just as an aside, this is because the compiler does not consider nested scopes when evaluating whether or not a variable is initialized, so it's a slightly more general matter.

Comment: @Magus: I don't think I can mark a comment as an accepted answer, but If I could - I would. I wanted to know how it looks in general.

Comment: @Magus, what do you mean by nested scope, I think it is because of the condition. If you have variable assignment like `{{{ i = 10; }}}`, instead of the `for` loop, there won't be any error. The error is because compiler can't evaluate condition

Comment: Ah, apparently I was wrong there. It does, however, extend to some contexts such as `try` and obviously `if`, but not a `using` block.

Comment: @Magus, `using` translates into `try-finally`, so I am not sure about that, but it if the compiler can't determine variable assignment by **static flow analysis** then there would be error.

Comment: @Kapol, the reason is not because of nested scope, it is because of static flow analysis specified in C# specs.